# QTP Object repository not showing test object property details

Tags: qtp

The application i'm working on is web based and addins used is web still my objecty repository doesnt show the object property details in the right pane in name value pair format. doesn't even shows the right pane like normally it would be a table. Instead shows blank.

can any one suggest why does this happen????

Thanks,
Priyan

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Quality Center?

We fixed it by re-installing the QC Client Side Add-in.
Quality Center( browser page)> Help > Add-ins Page > Client Side Setup > Download Add-in
Reinstall the add -in.

Hope this works for you.

Answer (score -1):

It seems to be a sporadic bug. Close and re-open the repo, and forget about this.

In my experience, this can sometimes happen if you open the OR manager, open a tsr file, and drilldown to a test object while "enable editing" is "off".

At least I occasionaly do see this anomaly in QTP 11.00 build 1018.